# C++ pass-by-reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I'm trying C++ pass-by-reference using this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
int square(int &x)
{
return x*x;
}
int main()
{
std::cout<<"Square of 4 is: "<<square(4)<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

But, when I try to run it, I get the following:

[image]

**UPDATE**

I get the following error after modifying the code based on @Pablo Santa Cruz's answer (I just screen captured part of the error):

[image]

Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: If possible, please copy and paste error messages into `<pre>` elements rather than posting screenshots. For one thing, some SO users (especially in the UK, and those on mobiles) pay by the MB. For another, we could then copy and paste the error & dissect it more readily.

Comment: @outis. Thanks for your note. Actually, I'm using `Cygwin` console, and I cannot find a way to copy the output.

Comment: @user588855, open window properties (in the Alt+Space menu) and enable mouse selection there. After that, just select the text with the mouse, then right click it and it will get into the clipboard. Also, the third reason to post text instead of screenshots is to allow Google to find it which is the main purpose of this place anyway.

Comment: @user...: the hard and only way to copy is this: 1. click on the icon in the top left corner of the console window, 2. Go to Edit->Select, 3. Select the text you want to copy, 4. press the enter key. The text will now be copied to the clipboard. Ctrl-v anywhere to paste!

Comment: @sergey: is that possible for the Cygwin console? (and to keep that by default, even when you quit and reopen it?)

Comment: @rubenvb, well my Cygwin console has selection enable by default, so it is certainly possible. I don't remember how I did it, though, maybe I edited the shortcut properties in the Start menu. Or maybe I just selected "remember this settings for all such windows" or something. But in any case, it works. Edit->Select works too, of course, I just missed it.

Comment: @Sergey: wow didn't know that... Now I wonder why it's disabled by default... grumble

Comment: Excellent point about search spiders, Sergey. @user588855: note that, while I say now to use `<pre>` for command output (though `<quote><pre>` or `<blockquote><pre>` would be better), the [`<samp>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.1) element is most appropriate, wich [someday SO might allow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user) (but not today).

Comment: Left click on the windows cygwin icon. From the drop down menu select "Properties". In the tab marked "Options" find "Quick Edit Mode" and make sure the check box is ticked. Click OK. The defaults should be saved for all new windows that you open. While you are in the "Properties Dialog" goto the "Layout" tab set the "Screen Buffer Size: Height" to "9999"

Comment: Did you use `-lboost_iostreams` to link the built iostreams library? See here for more info: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass a constant (`4`) if you are expecting a reference.

You **must** pass a variable:

```
int n = 4;
square(n);
```

Having said that, you probably want something like this:

```
void square(int &x)
{
   x = x*x;
}
```

Not a function returning an int.

Comment: When I do that I get the error shown in the `UPDATE` in my post. And, why don't I return a value and instead do `void`? Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You cannot pass temporaries to non-constant references.

Make `square` accept a `const int &`:

```
int square(const int &x)
{
    return x*x;
}
```

Comment: This is where const references by default are nice. No constant problems `;)`. Only non-const your reference arguments when you will modify them in the function.

Comment: For small types as `int` it is even better to just pass by value.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of § 8.5.3 5 of C++03:

> A reference to type “*cv1* T1” is initialized by an expression of type “*cv2* T2” as follows:
>
> - If the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “*cv1* T1” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* T2,” or
>   - has a class type (i.e., T2 is a class type) and can be implicitly converted to an lvalue of type “*cv3* T3,” where “*cv1* T1” is reference-compatible with “*cv3* T3” 92) (this conversion is selected by enumerating the applicable conversion functions (13.3.1.6) and choosing the best one through over- load resolution (13.3)),
>
>   then the reference is bound directly to the initializer expression lvalue in the first case, and the reference is bound to the lvalue result of the conversion in the second case. In these cases the reference is said to *bind directly* to the initializer expression. [*Note:* the usual lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are not needed, and therefore are suppressed, when such direct bindings to lvalues are done. ]
>
>   Otherwise, the reference shall be to a non-volatile const type (i.e., *cv1* shall be const).
>
>   - If the initializer expression is an rvalue, with T2 a class type, and “*cv1* T1” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* T2,” the reference is bound in one of the following ways (the choice is implementation-defined.
>
>     - The reference is bound to the object represented by the rvalue (see 3.10) or to a sub-object within that object.
>     - A temporary of type “*cv1* T2” [sic] is created, and a constructor is called to copy the entire rvalue object into the temporary. The reference is bound to the temporary or to a sub-object within the temporary.
>   - Otherwise, a temporary of type “*cv1* T1” is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy initialization (8.5). The reference is then bound to the temporary. If T1 is reference-related to T2, *cv1* must be the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv- qualification than, *cv2*; otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

Above, "*cv**" refers to the modifiers "const" and "volatile", and "T*" refer to type names. For example, `const int` (*cv* = "const", T = "int"), `const volatile std::string` (*cv* = "const volatile", T = "std::string"), `char*` (*cv* = "", T = "char*").

In short, [rvalues](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/227) are allowed to bind only to const references.

## Update

If your `square` now returns void (code or it didn't happen), then the new error is because there is no `operator<<(std::out&, void)`.

Comment: What do you mean by `temporaries`? Thanks.

Comment: outis. You are right. I shouldn't have inserted the function call in `std::cout<<`. Thanks

Comment: I should have written "rvalue" (see update). In simple terms, an 'lvalue' is a 'real object' (i.e. it exists in memory & has an address), while an 'rvalue' is the result of an expression (it doesn't have an address; it's usually stored in a register or an instruction). No address, so it can't be referenced, since references are based on object addresses. See "rvalue" link in answer for more. There are a number of SO questions about lvalues & rvalues, and about const references, so also check this site.

Comment: Also, a web search for "c++ temporaries" should turn up better info than I could provide here.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler creates a temporary object for constant `4` which can not be passed to a function as a non-const reference.  Create a `int` object in `main` and pass it to the function or take the function parameter by const-reference or by copy.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
int square(int& x);
```

says that the function `square` may change its argument (although it doesn't really).  So to call `square(4)` is ridiculous: the program needs to be ready to change the number 4.

As people have noted, you can either change the function to specify that it won't change its argument:

```
int square(const int& x); // pass reference to const type
// OR
int square(int x);        // pass by value
```

Or you can call your original `square` using a value that can be modified.

```
int square(int& x);
// ...
int num = 4;
square(num);
// now (as far as the compiler knows) num might no longer be 4!
```

Answer (score 0):

A reference must be an l-value-- basically, something you can see on the left side of an assignment statement.

So basically, you need to assign to a variable in `main` first. Then you can pass it into `square`.

Answer (score 0):

A reference aliases another variable. "4" is not a variable, and therefore your reference has nothing to alias. The compiler therefore complains.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is this:

```
#include <iostream>
int square(int x)
{
    return(x * x);
}
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Square of 4 is: "<< square(4) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Did you notice how I got rid of the `&` in `int square(int &x)`? The `&` means pass-by-reference. It takes a variable. The `4` in `square(4)` is a constant.

Using pass-by-reference, you can change the value of x:

```
void square2(int &x)
{
    x = x * x;
    return;
}
```

Now:

```
int x = 5;
square2(x);
// x == 25
```

Although, I don't think you want this. (Do you??) The first method is a lot better.